# Using ASP.NET Razor not MVC3 how do I allow html to render in a post? What method?

Tags: razor

I am familiar with the [AllowHtml] parameter in MVC3, but I am building a site based on Asp.net and Razor not inline with MVC3. How do I allow users to enter html in their post and not get that error message? What property or setting do I need to make to allow the html to pass through? I am using LINQ to talk to the database and the property I would like to allow html for is the Body property.

var Body = Request["Body"];

Answer (score 2):

Like this...

```
Request.Unvalidated("Body")
```